# How to read a static text file on the frontend without http request using javascript?

Tags: javascript

in our webapp's public folder, I have a text file. I want to read this text file and output parts of it to the screen. I've searched around and all I can find is how you'd read a text file when it's uploaded through an `input` or using an http request which is not possible for us at the moment.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: iframe? It will do an http request though

Comment: These reading-local-textfile questions are becoming more demanding every day. The next question will be, "using JS, how you can read a local textfile without a browser" ...

Comment: what is "the screen"? A web page? If you want to load something from a server into a webpage you have to use http. Unless your webapp has server-side code which can read the file from the disk and then include the contents within a web page which it is building? Or are you talking about doing this outside the context of the webapp? The question is pretty unclear. Why a http request "is not possible" is a bit baffling as well, I think you need to clarify the whole thing

Comment: @ADyson this file is already available to the webpage since it's a public resource

Comment: right then. So what's the problem?? Really not sure what you're getting at

Answer (score 0):

You have to send an HTTP request to the server for getting value of the TXT files.
Both of XMLHTTPREQUESTS and Iframes send an HTTP GET REQUEST.It's impossible to do it.
But if You don't want to send HTTP requests & your txt files aren't large,You can:
1-print the value of the txt file in the html page with your server-side language(for Example:PHP,ASP,...)
2-Then you can find the value of file from the html doucument body by using Javascript.